# Nextjs change /pages/api to /pages/myApi?

Tags: next.js

Next has a built in API route
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

It uses /pages/**api**

Is it possible to change the default path from /**api**/* to something else like /**myApi**/*?

I was thinking about adding it to exportPathMap
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

I believe you can't change the `/api` path because [Next.js looks specifically in that location](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/bb9bb64864dc4ed609030d6b0a94bd5b53873b06/packages/next/src/lib/is-api-route.ts).

```js
export function isAPIRoute(value?: string) {
  return value === '/api' || Boolean(value?.startsWith('/api/'))
}
```

If you want the `/api` directory to function as any other directory in `/pages`, you can use [Rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites). It could look like the following:

```js
//next.config.js

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [{ source: '/api/:path*', destination: '/another-directory/:path*' }]
  },
}
```

In this case, a request for `/api` would serve the content of `/another-directory`.

Alternatively, you can create a custom server for API routes, but note that you may need to disable or overwrite the default file system routing.

For more information, refer to the following Next.js docs:

- [Custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)
- [Disable file-system routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing)
- [RFC: Custom Routes](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9081)

Comment: +Up for pointing to RFC. Thanks!